# Is it possible to get a list of procedures created with WITH EXECUTE?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

Is it possible to get a list of stored procedures create with `WITH EXECUTE`?

I tried looking at `sys.procedures`, but they all have the principal set to `null`, and I know there are some procedures created this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [sys.sql_modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx):

```
SELECT p.name, m.execute_as_principal_id
  FROM sys.procedures AS p
  INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules AS m
  ON p.[object_id] = m.[object_id]
  WHERE m.execute_as_principal_id IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY p.name;
```

If you need to identify explicit `EXECUTE AS CALLER` vs. no `EXECUTE AS` (which are functionally the same), you'll need to parse `sys.sql_modules.definition`, which is far from foolproof (since `EXECUTE AS` can appear in many different contexts, including inside comments and string literals).